# git repo shared betwixt mac and windows causing line ending woes

Tags: git

I have a strange issue. My colleague uses a mac, and after pulling his branch it immediately thought I had been making changes to the files.

I couldn't reset or stash these changes, so followed the advice here https://xkcd.com/1597/ and deleted the repo.

I cloned it, and immediately had the same problem.

I then commented out this from gitattributes

```
#* text=auto
```

And all the uncommitted changes were gone.

Can anyone explain whats going on and how we can configure git to avoid this in the future?

Thanks